# Django ORM: recursive query with select_related and prefetch_related

Tags: django, recursion, django-models, django-orm, recursive-query

Consider having a family tree, **Grandpa**, **Father** and **Son** models.

Facing 2 problems fetching the tree..

**First**: if we need to fetch all family member we would use recursion for that.

psudo code:

```
* get person
* if person has a childPerson
* execute first step
```

**Second**: if we want to breakdown the results by filtering

psudo code:

```
* get person 'Grandpa' (and filter results for grandpa if filter applied)
* if person has a childPerson (father)
* execute first step (with filter result 'Father' if filter applied) //filter changes here and changes again with 'Son'
```

> How To apply this approach with Django ORM and Models?

because I'm searching for days I found [this link](https://youtu.be/qDyxmgWkjvI) might help to figure out solution (the closest to my approach), but need expert support to make code works for the approach.

Comment: check this django package  https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/    for hierarchical data

Comment: @DimitrisKougioumtzis I had a look on it, this may help with first issue, but how to achieve second one ?

Comment: django-mptt has two functions for each node in the tree  the get_ancestors method and get_descendants method  so you can read the documentation and apply the  filtering you need